# ffmpeg snap permission denied accessing encrypted folder

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, permissions, snapcraft

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and have most of my home folder in an EncFS filesystem. I have ffmpeg installed as a snap and it won't access files in the EncFS filesystem.

```
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

It also had the same error when accessing any folder not part of /home partition (for example on a second mounted harddrive) and also smb shares. I tried adding the removable-media connection but no joy. In fact I tried adding every connection. I do have a workaround for the other harddrives and the smb share by installing in --devmode (obviously not ideal). Is this a bug or a lack of snap understanding on my part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to quit using snaps and just install with apt or build from source.